# Minimal gui for Eclipse Indigo on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gui, eclipse

I'd like to install Eclipse I could use via VNC on a minimal Ubuntu 10.04 installation, but without the unnecessary bells and whistles that come with gnome-desktop. All I really need to do in an X-environment is access Eclipse via VNC. The rest will be done in terminal.

How can it be best accomplished? Is Gnome the only gui option for Eclipse?

Short explaination (as maybe there are other, simpler options, than what I'm asking about): I've got a single board computer with minimal Ubuntu 10.04 installed. The SBC is connected to an Arduino based embedded system collecting data. After the data acquisition I process them with the SBC. I'd like to be able to do programming directly on the SBC to speed up and simplify development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse and Gnome are not much related. Gnome is your **Desktop Environment**, and Eclipse IDE is just a GUI-based **application** - it will run on top of any window manager, as long as all the libraries are in place.

For a very light-weight desktop, yet easy to use, you might have a look at **Fluxbox**. It is small and fast and should be enough for your needs. Other possible options are e.g. **XFCE** and **LXDE**.

Comment: Wow, I can't even vote up with my reputation... Thanks for the answer. I eventually went with gnome-core, seems light-enough for me. I found a very nice tutorial eventually: [click](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Install-VNC.html)

Comment: OK, I earned it, +1 :)